# Android - High phone resource usage causing low volume on one headphone?

Tags: android, audio, resources, puredata, libpd

I am using libpd (Pure Data) on Android in order to make an application that can be used as a low budget hearing aid. My original design for the "audio engine" had 7 filters, and the volume from both headphones was the same. I changed the design to have 14 filters and now the right headphone has low volume.

Running the engine on my laptop produces the same volume on both ears. I tried running all the audio processing on it's own thread, but I am not sure if I did this correctly.

So to boil the question down.

1. Is low volume on one ear a possible side effect of using too many resources?
2. Is my implementation of creating a new thread correct?

   ```
   public class CircleOfFifths extends Activity {

   private static final String TAG = "GuitarTuner";
   private PdUiDispatcher dispatcher;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       initGui();

       new Thread(new Runnable() { 
           public void run(){        
               try {
                   initPd();
                   loadPatch();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                   finish();
               }            }
       }).start();



   }

   private void initGui() {
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }

   private void initPd() throws IOException {
       // Configure the audio glue
       // int sampleRate = AudioParameters.suggestSampleRate();

       int sampleRate = AudioParameters.suggestSampleRate();
       int inpch = AudioParameters.suggestInputChannels();
       int outch = AudioParameters.suggestOutputChannels();
       PdAudio.initAudio(sampleRate, inpch, outch, 4, true);

       // Create and install the dispatcher dispatcher = new PdUiDispatcher();
       // PdBase.setReceiver(dispatcher);
   }

   private void loadPatch() throws IOException {
       File dir = getFilesDir();
       IoUtils.extractZipResource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.patch),
               dir, true);
       File patchFile = new File(dir, "microphone.pd");
       PdBase.openPatch(patchFile.getAbsolutePath());
       PdAudio.startAudio(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       PdAudio.startAudio(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       PdAudio.stopAudio();
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using too much CPU shouldn't effect volume at all. It seems more likely one of your filters is causing a gain less than 1 on that channel.

Your thread looks fine to me.  I'm not 100% sure that calling finish on a non-UI thread is legal, but if it isn't you can add a runOnUiThread there